# Неудаляемые миграции в Laravel5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Создал миграцию. Класс в ней назывался "CreatePagesDefault". Затем мне эта миграция стала больше не нужна. Удалил ее. Для этого удалил файл миграции. Теперь, когда я пытаюсь заново создать все таблицы при помощи миграций, то выскакивает ошибка:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Class 'CreatePagesDefault' not found

Команда `composer dump-autoload` ничего не меняет. Пытался даже удалить файл `autoload.php` composer-а и заново создать. Никакого эффекта. Пытался во всем фрэймворка найти место, где сохранено название класса "CreatePagesDefault", но его находит только в логах - больше нигде.

Так как все-таки удалить миграцию? Где же эта информация хранится, в каком файле спрятана? На всякий случай оставлю здесь полный текст ошибки с трассировкой:

```
[2015-11-09 07:19:04] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'CreatePagesDefault' not found' in /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:324
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(133): Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException->__construct()
#1 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(118): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError()
#2 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(0): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#3 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(215): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->resolve()
#4 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(194): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runDown()
#5 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/ResetCommand.php(69): Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->reset()
#6 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(503): Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\ResetCommand->fire()
#7 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array()
#8 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(150): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#9 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute()
#10 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#11 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(166): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
#12 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/RefreshCommand.php(44): Illuminate\Console\Command->call()
#13 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(503): Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\RefreshCommand->fire()
#14 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array()
#15 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(150): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#16 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute()
#17 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#18 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(838): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
#19 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(189): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#20 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(120): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#21 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#22 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#23 /home/www/blog.loc/laravel/artisan(0): {main}()
#24 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в миграции хранился код для отката изменений (метод `down`).
Верным решением было бы сначала откатить ненужную миграцию с помощью команды

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

И только после этого ее удалять. Сейчас у вас в базе данных в таблице `migrations` сохранилась запись о выполненной некогда миграции, которую вы удалили, а вот самого файла уже нет.

#### Что можно сделать сейчас:

1. Удалите из таблицы `migrations` в базе данных запись о вашей миграции
2. После этого выполните команду `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Спасибо. Правда, пришлось удалить все таблицы в БД, благо это было не критично.